# Changing bitrate of mp3 in ffmpeg - file doesnt run

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, mp3

I am writing a small mp3 conversion tool. We upload a mp3 file & would like to convert it to a 96kbps file & a 320 kbps file. I have written the conversion script & it runs. But these files do not play.

Am i missing something?

the code i've written is:

```
/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i test.mp3 -vn -ar 441000 -ac 2 -ab 96k -f mp2 music/96/test.mp3 2>&1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major issues here:

1. The audio rate you're setting (`-ar 441000`) is incorrect. You want 44.1 kHz (`-ar 44100`).
2. You're forcing the use of MPEG2 audio (`-f mp2`), which is not what you want, and is probably not supported by the player you're using either. Leave that option out entirely; the `.mp3` extension on the output file will be used as a hint anyway.

Comment: Hi there! Yes it does run but gets corrupted. Trying to use JPlayer for playback.
Runs in the default player of Firefox, doesn't run in default player of Chrome, Safari & Opera.